# data lost while transfering

Tags: 12.04

I have windows and Ubuntu partitioned systems
when I cut 5gb data from Ubuntu download folder and pasted in local disk folder in ubuntu,
only 1gb data was there and 4gb data lost so how can I retrieve my lost data? please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it archive file before you move to local disk, so please make the data as .zp or eny other archiver. Then move it to local disk. Here data loss will not occur.

In this case, you have to retrieve old data. For that you can use the open source application, [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) you can download it [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and follow the [instructions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

Another way to install,

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

and open it,

```
sudo testdisk
```

From testdisk you can retrieve deleted data from any drive.